# Lista de tarefas em Javascript

Tags: javascript

Preciso realizar uma lista de tarefas em javascript que pega o que o usuário escreve em um input e cria uma div contendo esse texto e um botão de remover, porém apenas o botão de remover está aparecendo no site. O código em JS está pegando o valor do input, mas o site não mostra o texto da tarefa. Segue o código:
html:

```
<body>
    <div id="searcher">
        <input id="tarefa" type="tarefa" name="tarefa">
        <button id="salvartarefa">Salvar</button>
    </div>
    <div id="container"></div>
    <script src="script.js"></script>
</body>
```

```
const button = document.querySelector("#salvartarefa");

const container = document.querySelector("#container");

button.addEventListener('click', () => {
    const valorDigitado = document.querySelector('#tarefa').value
    const novaDiv = document.createElement('div');
    const textbox = document.createElement("p");
    const removeButt = document.createElement('button');
    removeButt.classList.add("reButt");
    novaDiv.classList.add("tarefas");
    removeButt.textContent = 'X';
    textbox.textContext = valorDigitado;
    container.appendChild(novaDiv);
    novaDiv.appendChild(textbox);
    novaDiv.appendChild(removeButt);
    removeButt.addEventListener('click', () => {
        container.removeChild(novaDiv);
    })
})
```

Comment: em `textbox.textContext = valorDigitado;` substitua por `textbox.innerText = valorDigitado;` **textContext** o significado do uso é define ou retorna o conteúdo de texto do nó especificado e todos os seus descendentes. Mas na forma que esta usando retorna null. por isso nao aparece nada em **p**

Answer (score -4, accepted):

```
textbox.textContext = valorDigitado;
```

O seu erro é simples, você digitou textContext. Não existe é **textContent**

```
textbox.textContent = valorDigitado;
```

**Revi seu código e o unico erro é esse você digitou errado na hora de programa-lo.**

Fiz aqui pelo meu e funcinou é só corrigir para textContent que vai funcionar.

Comment: Não cumprimente e não agradeça não nas publicações. Veja [Que tipo de comportamento é esperado dos usuários?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/behavior). [Perguntas sobre erros de digitação não devem ser respondidas](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/559/137387), esse tipo de pergunta não ajuda ninguém além do autor da pergunta assim fugindo da finalidade do site que é criar uma repositório de perguntas e respostas que possam ser alcançadas, via mecanismos de busca, por outros usuários com problemas similares e assim reaproveitando as soluções ao longo do tempo.